# Testcafe tests not able to run on a vpn but able to run on a remote desktop

Tags: node.js, automation, ui-automation, testcafe, browser-automation

I've been banging my head against the proverbial wall for too long and wondering if anyone has experienced the same issue and how they've managed to resolve it.

In a nutshell, testcafe scripts work as expected when remotely loging in to my work desktop, however, if I run the same testcafe scripts through a VPN then I get **A request to "https://website.com/page" has failed**.

This is my package.json

**"ssc": "testcafe chrome ./Fixtures/**

This is the code that I'm using to connect to the website:

```
fixture `Checking layout of website`.page `https://website.com/page`
                                       .beforeEach( async t=>
{
 console.log("Logging in")
 await t.useRole(regularAccUser);
})

test('Checking stuff', async t=>
{
   await t.takeScreenshot()
})
```

The error being displayed:

```
**A request to "https://website.com/page" has failed.
      Use quarantine mode to perform additional attempts to execute this test.
      You can find troubleshooting information for this issue at "https://go.devexpress.com/TestCafe_FAQ_ARequestHasFailed.aspx".
      Error details:
      Failed to perform a request to the resource at "https://website.com/page" because of an error.
      Error: Parse Error**
```

The following is the log file:

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'ssc' ]
2 info using npm@6.14.4
3 info using node@v10.21.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'pressc', 'ssc', 'postssc' ]
5 info lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~pressc: smoke9@0.0.0
6 info lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: smoke9@0.0.0
7 verbose lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Automation\smoke\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\windows\system32;C:\windows;C:\windows\System32\Wbem;C:\windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\150\DTS\Binn\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Users\ext-krishnanv\Desktop\Eclipse\eclipse\java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.222-2.b10.ojdkbuild.windows.x86_64\bin;C:\Installation\spark-2.2.1\bin;C:\Installation\scala\bin;C:\Anaconda3;C:\Anaconda3\Scripts;C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\ProgramData\DockerDesktop\version-bin;C:\apache-jmeter-5.3\bin;C:\Users\beckettj1\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\<username>\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: CWD: C:\Automation\smoke
10 silly lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'testcafe chrome ./Fixtures/<subdirectory>/' ]
11 silly lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
12 info lifecycle smoke9@0.0.0~ssc: Failed to exec ssc script
13 verbose stack Error: smoke9@0.0.0 ssc: `testcafe chrome ./Fixtures/<subdirectory>/`
13 verbose stack Exit status 1
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:332:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:982:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:259:5)
14 verbose pkgid smoke9@0.0.0
15 verbose cwd C:\Automation\smoke
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17134
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "ssc"
18 verbose node v10.21.0
19 verbose npm  v6.14.4
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 1
22 error smoke9@0.0.0 ssc: `testcafe chrome ./Fixtures/<subdirectory>/`
22 error Exit status 1
23 error Failed at the smoke9@0.0.0 ssc script.  **<----IS THIS A RED HERRING??---->**
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

./Fixtures/ is the location of all my js/ts scripts

Comment: Does this page open successfully in the browser (without TestCafe) with the same VPN?

Comment: Many thanks for your reply - Yes it does. It's a works VPN using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client

Comment: Though not the exact issue, I remember facing a similar one.  Could you try without npm and see if it works? Example: testcafe chrome test1.js, instead of npm run.

Comment: Nah, that doesn't work either.  I'm not sure that it would be related to npm to be honest but how testcafe handles https over a vpn.

Comment: "Parse Error" indicates that something goes wrong with parsing the request via the TestCafe Hammerhead proxy. You can set the environment variable as follows:
```set DEBUG="hammerhead:destination*"```

Then, run your tests. As a result, the debug information about the request pipeline will be shown. It will include more information about the error. It would be very helpful if you share these logs with us.

Also, you can try to force NodeJS to use the legacy http-parser:

```set NODE_OPTIONS='--http-parser=legacy'```

Comment: My workplace also uses cisco anyconnect and I had an issue running tests remotely for a while, try adding `--hostname localhost` option when running